# How to change column Values of data imported in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change column values of data imported in python.I have imported an excel workbook using pandas.

```
Data=pd.read_excel(r"...\Report.xlsx")
```

I want to write a function to import excel and change column value(Column Name-Name) and Values('C' has to be changed to 'A' and 'E' to 'B). The below Table data is sample table and data.

```
Name       Place
A        UK
B        Aus
C        US
D        AFR
E        CHN
```

My code is

```
import pandas as pd    
def read_csv(filename):    
        string_data = pd.read_excel(filename)    
if 'C' in string_data['Name']:    
    string_data['Name'].replace('C','A',inplace=True)
if 'E' in string_data['Name']:    
    string_data['Name'].replace('E','B',inplace=True)    
result=string_data.groupby(["Name"])["Place"].count().reset_index(name='result_count')    
   return result
```

Here the if condition in function doesn't working and values are not changed. Am i writing condition wrongly. How to change column values and bring result? Could anyone help on writing this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue that `inplace` replace does *not* work on DataFrame columns, because you're operating on a copy, and nothing happens.

I recommend the following fixes:

1. Don't call `replace` multiple times. It's a bottleneck, so best to call it once with multiple replacements.
2. Remove `inplace`, and just assign the result back.
3. Use `value_counts` instead of `groupby` + `count`.

```
string_data['Name'] = string_data['Name'].replace({'C' : 'A', 'E' : 'B'})
string_data['Name'].value_counts()

A    2
B    2
D    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

---

As a further optimisation, notice that the output of `value_counts` is a *lot* smaller than the input.

So just call `value_counts` on the original, and perform a `replace` on the result.

```
v = string_data['Name'].value_counts()
v.index = v.index.to_series().replace({'C' : 'A', 'E' : 'B'})
v.groupby(level=0).sum()

A    2
B    2
D    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```